# Firestore Query with .where conditions

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following query:

```
Query postsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts')
  .where('postType', isNotEqualTo: 'Discussion') //post types - Simple, featured, discussion
  .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
  .where('group', isEqualTo: groupName) //india, usa, pakistan
  .limit(perPage);
```

The query runs if i remove this :

```
.where('postType', isNotEqualTo: 'Discussion')
```

Anyone knows what i am doing wring here?

Comment: Have you declared the index?

Comment: what index are you talking about ?

Comment: Also, if its' a compound query, then the vscode logs show the link in order to build index for the query but the logs aren't showing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you haven't declare the [Firestore index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) corresponding to your query.

As explained in the doc:

> Cloud Firestore ensures query performance by requiring an index for
> every query. The indexes required for the most basic queries are
> automatically created for you. As you use and test your app, **Cloud
> Firestore generates error messages that help you create additional
> indexes your app requires**.
>
> ...
>
> If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error. **The error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console**.

So, add a `catch()` block to the code used to execute the query and you will get the link in the error message. Note: This link is to be opened (once) via a web browser, not via the Flutter app.

Comment: Will do in a moment. Let me get back to you.

Comment: I added try-catch block with showDialog widget in case query returns an error. Still its giving the error and not showing the link in the logs to build index for this compound query. i have build indexes for the queries and there is always a link in the logs but in this case logs are not displaying anything.

Comment: "Note: This link is to be opened (once) via a web browser, not via the Flutter app." I know about this and had build indexes multiple times in the past.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your indexes, taken from the console?

Comment: sure i can but i changed the data(groupName) for the query and already updated the firestore and now the query is working perfectly. Doesn't know what the problem was but it seems to work with the new method.

Comment: Also, thanks for the help as you suggested the method to identify the problem.